# Get bad circle and arc when call create_oval and create_arc with large width in tkinter Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter-canvas

I got a bad circle when the border width increased, not sure why the yellow ring looks wrong appearance in my WIN10 / python 3.10.1 / tkinter 8.6.12

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

frame1 = Frame(root)
frame1.pack(side='top')
for i in range(-1, 2):
    canvas = Canvas(frame1, width=300, height=300, bg='green')
    canvas.pack(side='left')
    canvas.create_oval(50, 50, 250+i, 250+i, width=81, outline='yellow')
    canvas.create_rectangle(50, 50, 250+i, 250+i)
    canvas.create_oval(50, 50, 250+i, 250+i, width=1)

frame2 = Frame(root)
frame2.pack(side='top')
for i in range(3):
    canvas = Canvas(frame2, width=300, height=300, bg='green')
    canvas.pack(side='left')
    canvas.create_arc(50, 50, 250, 250, start=0, extent=(i+1)*90, style='arc', width=81, outline='yellow',)

root.mainloop()
```

Following figure show that

- Flat area shown at about 0 degree for all circles.
- Round cap for 1st arc drawn to 90 degree, sometime it also happened when drawn to 180 or 270 degree but not sure when it will happened exactly.

Maybe it is about the cap and join styles, but don't know what the options for them.

[image]

Comment: It looks correct for me on Linux.  What operating system are you using?

Comment: My platform is WIN10 / python 3.10.1 / tkinter 8.6.12.

Comment: Does the problem still persist when you open the window displaying the circle in full screen?

Comment: Yes, three canvas kept nothing changed and just shifted to center of left side after window maximized.